# App using StartCom SSL Certificate possible?

Tags: windows-phone-7

as StartCom SSL Certificates are not preinstalled on WP7: is there a way to include the SSL Certificate from StartCom (StartCom Inc, Israel) in the App on the Marketplace, thus enabling the App to use this certificate to make ssl connections (HTTPWebRequest) to our server?

As we are already have the Webservice running with this certificate for iOS and Android devices we don't want to change the whole thing for WP7..

Thanks and happy X-Mas,
                         Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps if you want to install certificate in Windows Phone 7 since there is no way to escape the certificate check.

http://joymonscode.blogspot.com/2011/11/installing-ssl-certificates-to-windows.html

Comment: thank you! this might work, as we can call internetexplorer on first app start to go to the .cer hosting site. That the user has to accept the installation of the certificate shouldnt be a problem :)

Comment: Got it ready, this is what I do: Get 404 in HttpWebRequest (checking internet is availble) => Messagebox to inform user what is about to happen with ok/cancel. Ok => WebBrowserTask with uri directly to the root certificate of StartCom. User then only has to press on the Shield and Accept and upon returning to my app everythings running :)